# Write project object to project file

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn to do some code transformation and one of the options of the program is to output the transformed source files. However I'd like to out put the project as well as a *.csproj file. The code I have for ouptutting the documents is

```
 foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
        {
            foreach (var doc in project.Documents)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(doc.FilePath);
                var directory = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(doc.FilePath), "output");
                if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                }
                var outputPath = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);

                using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(outputPath)))
                {
                    doc.GetText().Write(writer);
                }
            }
        }
```

and I'd like to insert a few lines to output the project as well, in the same directory as the files

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can output changes to both documents and projects to their original locations using the `Workspace.ApplyChanges()` method.  Note that not all possible changes to projects are supported by `ApplyChanges` however.

Generally, for sufficiently complicated changes to project files you should use the MSBuild APIs directly to manipulate the .csproj files.

Comment: I'd like to output a copy of the project file to a different location. Is that possible?

Comment: Not using the Roslyn APIs.  I'm not sure about the msbuild ones.